# Does a topological isomorphism between monothetic groups preserve the generator?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, cyclic-groups, topological-groups, group-isomorphism

Suppose that $\phi$ is a topological isomorphism between the topological groups $G=\overline{\{x^{n}:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}}$ and $H=\overline{\{y^{n}:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}}$. Can we conclude that $\phi(x)=y$?

Since $\phi$ is a homeomorphism, I think that we can deduce that $\phi(x)$ also generates $H$:
$$H=\phi(G)=\phi(\overline{\{x^{n}:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}})=\overline{\phi(\{x^{n}:n\in\mathbb{Z}\})}=\overline{\{\phi(x)^{n}:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}}.$$
But is this sufficient to conclude that $\phi(x)=y$?

Comment: So you are assuming that $\phi$ is only a homeomorphism and not a homomorphism?

Comment: @Randall By 'topological isomorphism' I mean isomorphism of groups + homeomorphism.

Comment: Group isomorphisms always preserve generators, but it need not fix particular ones.  Just think:  $\phi(x)=-x$ sends generators to generators on $\mathbb{Z}$, but it doesn't fix them.

Comment: One can suppose $G=H$, so the question becomes whether the group of topological automorphisms of $G$ is trivial (= reduced to identity). The answer is then no as soon as $|G|>2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no, because generators need not be unique.  Give the group $\mathbb{Z}$ the discrete topology.  Then $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ by $\phi(x)=-x$ is an isomorphism in the category of topological groups.  However, if the domain and codomain were taken to be $\langle 1 \rangle$ then $\phi$ does not map fixed generator to fixed generator.

Note that $\phi(1)=-1$ does in fact generate the codomain $\mathbb{Z}$, but this is not the "chosen" generator at the outset.  The problem is, of course, that generators are not unique (even in the monothetic situation).

Comment: Ah I see! I noticed that I forgot to mention that my groups $G$ and $H$ are compact. Does this change the situation?

Comment: No.  Do the same thing with $\mathbb{Z}_3$, which has two generators, more than one automorphism, and is compact with the discrete topology.

Comment: Of course. Thank you!